# List feature in Wordpress shows different results in Firefox and Opera

Tags: wordpress, firefox, opera, html-lists

I use Wordpress and created an ordered list on my new page.

[Here is the link to the page](http://www.gesundepfunde.com/abnehmtipps-unendliche-liste-tipps-zum-erfolgreichen-abnehmen/)

I placed one image on the left side of the page next to number 7. When I open this page with Firefox 3.6.13, everything is displayed correctly. However, in Opera 11, the "7" is missing next to the image. The number 7 is displayed behind the image.

Do you know how I can display the number 7 next to the image in Opera too?

Thank you very much.

Nico

Answer (score 1):

The *float* of the image class *.align-left, .alignleft* is indenting your *li* and thus hiding the number. But I couldn't find a quick fix for it, sorry :/

Chrome, Safari and IE8 on Windows are having the same 'problem' of not showing the number 7 in front of the element. Maybe it's correct and just a rendering hack/bug in FF?

**Idea:** You could put a span or p element around the text, separating it from the image - but that's not the friendliest for editors later. Although if you use alignright it looks better ;)

Have you tried the debug tools in Opera? Right-click and then "Inspect Element" for example on the image or some other element to activate them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will probably just place all images on the right side. :-)

Comment: Would you except my answer then, please :)